# Imagick unable to open module file

Tags: php, image, dll, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to use Imagick with PHP. I have installed the program, replaced the core dll files, loaded the dll extension with xampp, but now I get this error:

> unable to open module file
>   `C:\Users\sudom\AppData\Local\ImageMagick\IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll': No such
>   file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/830

This is the line causing the problem: `$image->setImageFormat('png');`.
I took a look to the AppData/Local folder, but there's no ImageMagick folder. If I place it there manually, it throws another error. 
I use:

- ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-Q16-x86-dll
- php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x86

Comment: please make sure imagechick dll file in this directory

Comment: @geekido in which directory?

Comment: maybe this could help https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: Does your ImageMagick install include all the needed delegates, especially, for PNG. See if it is listed from `magick -version`.

Answer (score 0):

Downlod the latest version from here
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

```
ImageMagick-7.0.7-12-Q16-x64-dll.exe
```

or

```
ImageMagick-7.0.7-12-Q16-x86-dll.exe
```

install, make sure adding the Imagick folder to the system PATH.
Optionally you can tick legacy utilities (convert, mogrify) during installation. and check in cmd 'magick -version'

> c:\convert --version Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-12 Q16 x64 2017-11-29
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Visual C++: 180040629
>   Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo
>   flif freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps
>   raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

---

Download php_imagick.dll from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.3/windows
meets your php version requirments, put in to ext folder of php and add it to php.ini file.

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

---

Than, go to http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/
find needed version

```
 3/27/2016  5:32 PM     32707238 ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc11-x64.zip
 3/27/2016  5:33 PM     31517070 ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc11-x86.zip
 3/27/2016  5:34 PM     38717224 ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip
 3/27/2016  5:34 PM     37376244 ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x86.zip
```

download package and put all the DLLs files from ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc1x-xxx.zip\bin\ except **ImageMagickObject.dll** to  ...\apache\bin\ and restart the apache service.

MUST WORK!

P.S. You can also find all the stuff from mentioned above resources for PHP 7.2 except pecl library. Need to wait for a while.